# Build full query from SQLAlchemy orm

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Ultimately I'm trying to use pandas read_sql which takes in a raw SQL query.

I'm trying to convert something like;

```
sql = str(session.query(Post).filter(Post.user_id=1))
```

That generates something like

```
select * from Post where user_id = %(user_id_1)
```

Is there any way to generate that query with the parameter already interpolated?

Comment: You could try passing that SQL string directly to `read_sql_query` along with `params={"user_id_1": 1}`. That would help you avoid the messiness of injecting literal values into the SQL command text.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm doing now.  It just seems like there should be a way to automatically do this with SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found, if we `str()` an ORM query we get the SQL command text with parameter placeholders using the paramstyle for our dialect:

```py
qry = session.query(Parent).filter(Parent.id == 1)
sql = str(qry)
print(sql)
"""console output:
SELECT parent.id AS parent_id, parent.lastname AS parent_lastname, parent.firstname AS parent_firstname 
FROM parent 
WHERE parent.id = %(id_1)s
"""
```

If we want to have the parameter values embedded in the SQL statement then we need to `.compile()` it:

```py
sql_literal = qry.statement.compile(
    compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True},
)
print(sql_literal)
"""console output:
SELECT parent.id, parent.lastname, parent.firstname 
FROM parent 
WHERE parent.id = 1
"""
```

(Standard disclaimers regarding SQL Injection apply.)